# Keep the name of the columns in a groupby with sum in a pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, sum

I have to do a groupby () in a pandas data frame and the result must be a data frame with the same columns (same name and same number). Example:

```
import pandas as pd

raw_data = {'first_name': ['Jason', 'Molly', 'Jason', 'Jake', 'Molly'], 
    'last_name': ['Miller', 'Jacobson', 'Miller', 'Milner', 'Jacobson'], 
    'age': [42, 73, 42, 24, 73], 
    'point_1': [4, 24, 31, 2, 93],
    'point_2': [25, 94, 57, 62, 70]}

df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'age', 
'point_1', 'point_2'])
```

If I try:

```
df.groupby(['first_name','last_name','age']).sum()
```

I have:

```
                          point_1  point_2
first_name last_name age                  
Amy        Cooze     73         3       70
Jake       Milner    24         2       62
Jason      Miller    42         4       25
Molly      Jacobson  52        24       94
Tina       Ali       36        31       57
```

and my columns are only:

```
df.groupby(['first_name','last_name','age']).sum().columns.values 

array(['point_1', 'point_2'], dtype=object)
```

but I also need the three initial columns.

Answer (score 2):

The cols you grouped by became the index. If you don't want that:

```
df.groupby(['first_name','last_name','age']).sum().reset_index()
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting `as_index` to `False` on the `groupby` call should do it.

```
df.groupby(['first_name','last_name','age'],as_index=False).sum()
```